# jQuery/regex failing selenium IDE test

Tags: jquery, regex, selenium, selenium-ide

I have some jQuery validation code that has to pass some tests on Selenium. However, every time I run the tests, different ones fail and different ones pass. For example, on one test, password to short will fail and password too long will pass. However, if I re-run the test, the opposite might happen!

This is the regex:

```
var password = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*(_|[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?])).{6,20}$/;
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
if($('#password').val() ==""){
$('#passwordErrorMsg').text("Your password must be between 6 and 20 characters. It must contain a mixture of upper and lower case letters, and at least one number or symbol.");  
}        
else if(password.test($('#password').val())){      
$('#passwordErrorMsg').text("OK");
}    
else($('#passwordErrorMsg').text("Your password must be between 6 and 20 characters. It must contain a mixture of upper and lower case letters, and at least one number or symbol."));
});
```

Any help in passing the Selenium Tests would be helpful and grateful, thanks.

Comment: @roasted, I think the regex is alright... it just checks for every necessary symbol with a lookahead, and then tests for string-length. @user1766599. You can remove the `_|` from your fourth lookahead. It should be taken care of by the character class. (This won't solve your problem though). Also your lasst error message does not fit the regex. Your regex requires a digit **and** a symbol.

Comment: Ho ok, i didnt have seen "It must contain a mixture of upper and lower case letters, and at least one number or symbol." ...

Answer (score 0):

```
/^((?<lowerCase>[a-z])|(?<upperCase>[A-Z])|(?<numberOrSymbol>[0-9+_!@#$%^&*.,?-])){6,20}(?(lowerCase)|(?!))(?(upperCase)|(?!))(?(numberOrSymbol)|(?!))$/
```

Start at begin of line.

Take 6-20 times either a lowercase letter, or an uppercase letter, or a NumberOrSymbol, meanwhile counting each type's occurrences.

Verify that each type has occurred at least once.

Verify that we're at the end of the line.

Notes on the regex presented in the question: it verifies presence of the required symbols, but it does NOT require that ALL characters in the pwd belong to one of the "stated" classes, it would for instance accept the string "aA3@\\\", which is probably not intended by the writer to be an acceptable password.